# Insert into SQL from 2 tables into 1 where some values exists between the two

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Sorry the title might be confusing but I will try to explain better here.  So I have 2 tables.

```
Table1
Name
Int
Decimal

Table2
Name
Int
Decimal
```

I am trying to combine the data into a third table.  It would look something like this

```
Table3
Name
Table1_Int
Table1_Decimal
Table2_Int
Table2_Decimal
```

The insert is not an issue.  The issue is I have a few names that exist in one table and not the other.  I still want these to show up, just with NULL values where there are no values.

Here is my stored proc

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT Name FROM Table3)
    INSERT INTO Table3(
        Name,
        Table1_Int,
        Table1_Decimal,
        Table2_Int,
        Table2_Decimal)
    SELECT 
        t.Name,
        AVG(t.Int) as Table1_Int,
        AVG(CAST(t.Decimal as decimal(6,2))) as Table1_Decimal
        AVG(a.Int) as Table2_Int,
        AVG(CAST(a.Decimal as decimal(6,2))) as Table2_Decimal
    FROM Table1 t
    JOIN Table2 a
    ON t.Name = a.Name
    GROUP BY t.Name
ELSE
    UPDATE Table3
    SET Name = Name
```

Is there anyway I can grab all names, no matter if they match between tables?

Comment: Use a left join...

Comment: haha wow.  Just wow

Comment: @JohnHC post that as answer so I can give you credit.  Thank you.  I feel like a dumb ass

Comment: If you're going to have records from the second table that aren't in the first then you may want to look at FULL OUTER JOIN  and on the Name field use a COALESCE to return the first non null value from either table.

Comment: @Rich Benner would that be better than using just a left join?

Comment: Yes, with a left join you'll return all records from table1 with matching records from table2. If you have any records in table 2 that aren't in table1 then these won't be returned (with a left join)

Comment: ok let me try that and I will let you know.  And yeah I have just noticed that with the left join on insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the basic logic of a FULL OUTER JOIN. I'd expect it to look something like this;

```
SELECT
COALESCE(t.name, a.name) name
,AVG(t.Int) t_int
,AVG(CAST(t.Decimal as decimal(6,2))) t_decimal
,AVG(a.Int) a_int
,AVG(CAST(a.Decimal as decimal(6,2))) a_decimal
FROM Table1 t
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 a
    ON t.name = a.name
GROUP BY COALESCE(t.name, a.name)
```

Comment: so if I do a select by itself, I see the values.  When I do the insert, I get the same results.  Could it be my IF/ELSE?

Comment: Deleted everything from the table and ran again and it worked.